# How to parse XML present in a jsp page into

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, jsp

How do I parse XML into HTML?

## Code

```
<snomed> 
<%
String selectsql = null;
DBConnection DBCon = null;
Connection Con = null;
PreparedStatement pstm = null;
ResultSet resultSet = null;
String snomedid = request.getParameter("snomedcode");

try {
    DBCon = new DBConnection();
    Con = DBCon.getConnection();
    selectsql = "select * from snomedicd10map where referencedComponentId=? ";
    pstm = Con.prepareStatement(selectsql);
    pstm.setString(1, snomedid);
    resultSet = pstm.executeQuery();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
while (resultSet.next()) {
    String maprule = null;
    maprule = (resultSet.getString("mapRule"));
    if (maprule.matches("OTHERWISE TRUE")
            || maprule.matches("TRUE")) {   
%>      
           <otherwise> 
           <snomedid><%=resultSet.getString("referencedComponentId")%></snomedid>
           <snomedname><%=resultSet.getString("sctName")%></snomedname> 
           <icdcode><%=resultSet.getString("mapTarget")%></icdcode>
           <icdname><%=resultSet.getString("icdName")%></icdname> 
           </otherwise>
<% 
    }}
%> <%
            DBCon = new DBConnection();
            Con = DBCon.getConnection();
            pstm = Con.prepareStatement(selectsql);
            pstm.setString(1, snomedid);
            resultSet = pstm.executeQuery();
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                String str = resultSet.getString("referencedComponentId");
                String[] pipe = resultSet.getString("mapRule").split("\\|");
                if (pipe.length > 1) {
        %> 
         <refinechoice> 
        <cell><%=pipe[1]%></cell> 
        </refinechoice> 
        <%
            }}
        %> <%
                String refId = request.getParameter("refId");
                String mapRule = request.getParameter("maprule");
                selectsql = "select * from snomedicd10map where referencedComponentId=? AND maprule = ? ";
                pstm = Con.prepareStatement(selectsql);
                pstm.setString(1, refId);
                pstm.setString(2, mapRule);
                resultSet = pstm.executeQuery();
                while (resultSet.next()) {
            %> 
            <refineproblem> 
            <snomedid><%=resultSet.getString("referencedComponentId")%></snomedid>
            <snomedname><%=resultSet.getString("sctName")%></snomedname> 
            <icdcode><%=resultSet.getString("mapTarget")%></icdcode>
            <icdname><%=resultSet.getString("icdName")%></icdname>
            </refineproblem> 
            <%
                }
            %>
             </snomed>
```

- I need to parse in another jsp page
- otherwise tagname need to get 1st
- refinechoice tag name need to get second then in refine choice type is radio button and after selecting any one refine choice and its need to get refine problem tag name 3rd
- how to get this in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer and, for example, firefox-based browsers expose different objects for XML parsing, so it's wise to use a JavaScript framework like jQuery to handle the cross-browsers differences.

A really basic example is:
var xml = "Beethoven";

var result = $(xml).find("album").text();

For more in-depth information, read the tutorial Easy XML Consumption using jQuery.

Note: jQuery does not really do any XML parsing whatsoever, it relies on the DOM innerHTML method and will parse it like it would any HTML so be careful when using HTML element names in your XML. But I think it works fairly good for simple XML 'parsing', but it's probably not suggested for intensive or 'dynamic' XML parsing where you do not upfront what XML will come down and this tests if everything parses as expected.